Synapse REST API Hierarchy
Synapse Pipeline
SOURCE: REST API  
SINK: CSV
Nested JSON personnel columns return NULL. 
Sink Copy Behaviour is set to flatten hierarchy.
"Advances": [
        {
           
            "Contract": "400997",
            "PostingDate": "2024-04-10",
            "PortfolioManagerName": "Jack Sparrow",
            "ContributionPerc": 0,
            "Personnel": [
                {
                    "Position": "Portfolio Manager",
                    "Number": "140169",
                    "Name": "Jack Sparrow",
                    "ContrShare": 100
                },
                {
                    "Position": "Credit Controller",
                    "Number": 18162,
                    "Name": "Clarke Kent",
                    "ContrShare": 0
                },
                {
                    "Position": "Implementation Officer",
                    "Number": 22451,
                    "Name": "Bruce Wayne",
                    "ContrShare": 0
                }
            ],

            "LastEdit": "2024-04-10T11:49:40Z",     
            "Area": "Gotham City"
        },

Every contract has multiple personnel, I need to flatten the output to give me personnel data for every contract.
Can anyone suggest how I would do this?

Your data has two level of nested Json. This needs to be flattened twice. This is not possible using copy activity because mapping of copy activity can flatten only once. For your case, you need to use dataflow activity. You need to use flatten activity twice in that. One to flatten the Advances[] and other to flatten Personnel[] array. Below is the approach in dataflow.

Take the source transformation with Json dataset. Give the Json settings as  Array of Json in source option.

Take the flatten transformation and unroll by Advances array.




Give the mapping as in below image in the flatten transformation.



Take another transformation and unroll by Personnel array.



Give the mapping for second flatten transformation as in below image.


Output of second flatten transformation


Is it working for you?
